Does a packed fridge cost the same as an an empty fridge? (Electricity cost)
Discounting initial power to bring an item into a frozen state, then is the electricity cheaper to leave my fridge empty; or is the cost the same for it being packed with frozen foods?
If my fridge is empty, will it draw less power (and therefore be less expensive) than if it is full of frozen food which needs to remain frozen at, say $0.25 per kW/h, for constant power applied at a cost of:
$$
\mathrm{Number\ of\ hours} \cdot 0.25 \cdot \left(\frac{\mathrm{Voltage} \cdot \mathrm{Amperage}}{1\ \mathrm{hour}}\right)
$$

duplicate

This question is similar to: Does an empty refrigerator require more power to stay cold than a full one?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"$0.25 per kW/h" - The unit is kWh, not kW/h. kW/h would mean an increase rate of power consumption, which makes no sense in this context.

If you leave a packed fridge and an empty fridge for a week, the same amount of heat will escape through the walls. The cost will be the same.
But it takes more energy to cool the food in a packed fridge than the air in an empty fridge. So the cost when you put room temperature food in is higher.
You will likely be opening the door more often the get food out of a packed fridge than an empty fridge.

On the other hand, when you open a fridge you might expect that a greater volume of cold air would escape from an empty fridge than a packed fridge.

@QuantumWiz: Trying to back-of-the-envelope the scale of this effect: according to this, the volumetric heat capacity of air is about 1/4000 of that of water.  A large household fridge is around 400L; so a full fridge-worth of air has the heat capacity of about 100ml of water, or around 100g of most foods.  That puts an upper bound on how much work is lost by opening a fridge; in practice the air is far from fully flushed, so I’d expect the effect to be significantly smaller.

Error, two cubes of 1 liter of iron, supported, one at 20° and the other at 30°, will modify their temperature, until they are at 25°, same example, but changing one of the two cubes, by one of air, they would be at 21° (fictitious value), since more mass, implies more capacity to retain temperature.Therefore, the full refrigerator (after reaching the lowest temperature) will consume less energy :).

The full fridge will cool more slowly hence the heat transport through the walls will be higher. This is just because of heat capacity and it is a transient effect not strongly related to the question.

I think there should be some difference in energy consumed by an empty fridge and a full fridge. @mmesser314 says

If you leave a packed fridge and an empty fridge for a week, the same
amount of heat will escape through the walls.

I am not sure about that. Maybe the following effect is not very significant, but... So cold (not heat) escapes through the walls, so the temperature of the walls should be somewhat higher than the temperature of the interior of the fridge. That means that the interior of the fridge will absorb some thermal radiation from the walls, and I would think food would absorb radiation better than air. There may be some other effects, but I still think there can be some difference in energy consumption.

the difference might actually go the other way - an empty fridge can more easily equalize the interior temperature, so the warmth of the walls will more directly affect the temperature sensor. Meanwhile in a packed fridge, the space near the walls may be insulated from the space near the sensor by the food - so we'd get a (slightly) higher temperature area between the walls and the pizza, which the temperature sensor does not notice and thus does not counter. Less temperature difference to the outside (in those insulated spaces) = less energy transfer... but yes, likely neglectable in scale

One more factor (other answers still being good)
A fridge full of food has much more heat capacity inside. This means that the thermostat will switch on and off at lower frequency - it will take more time for the interior to heat up to the point of switching the thermostat on and then will take more time to cool it down to the point of the thermostat switching off.
This can act two ways:

On one hand, at switching on, the compressor runs minute or two without actually cooling anything, just to get to the proper working distribution of temperature and pressure. At switching off, the cooling action stops more or less immediately. We have a minute or two worth of electricity wasted, more or less frequently (see above). So the full fridge may actually be consuming somewhat less energy.

On the other hand, running the cooling system longer means building up heat around the external heat exchanger and gradually lowering the cooling efficiency. For a properly installed domestic fridge, this is probably the less prominent effect, but it acts against the first one.


Both effects will probably be overwhelmed by the differend temperature field of a full / empty fridge. Full and empty fridges have profoundly different heat transmission properties inside the cooled volume. This will affect the thermostat function and the average temperature (and the heat ingress thereof). The effect can be in both directions, depending on the thermostat sensor placement.

If the fridge remains closed there ideally is no difference. The heat transport is determined by the temperature difference between inside and outside and the heat conductivity of the walls. This assumes a uniform temperature inside. If some parts of the packed fridge are less well cooled then others the temperature distribution and the heat transmission will depend on the loading. In general this will result in less heat loss at the expense of less adequate cooling.
